# strange angular bug: angular.element('<option-anything>') fails

Tags: angularjs

I just noticed that

```
angular.element('<option-anything>')
```

fails to compile.  It returns an empty array.  It seems to be related to the phrase "option-".
any insights?

Comment: have you tried closing the tag? `<option-anything />` or `<option-anything></option-anything>`

Comment: Works fine as written in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yd4j2/

Comment: yes, indeed.  looks like it is a bug with version 1.2.18 and later

Answer (score 0):

it appears to be a bug in the lastest version of angular.js